# Stability by multiplication with a matrix?

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I am wondering how to prove (or disprove) that

- if $A$ is a matrix $n \times n$  and
- $b_1....b_k$ are $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
- so that  $Ab_1, ..., Ab_{k}$ is a set of generators in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

then so is the family of vectors $b_{1},...,b_{k}$.

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic. This is a pure math question, linear algebra to be precise. And it lacks information: Set of generators of what space? If it is the full space, then k>=n and A is invertible.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about maths, not programming.

Comment: Now duplicated as (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691057/how-to-prove-this-implication). Copied my answer over, feel free to close or delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, this question is asking if rank(A*B)=n implies rank(B)=n. This is a consequence of

rank(A*B) <= min( rank(A), rank(B) )

and the fact that for reasons of dimension of the spaces involved, rank(A) <= n and rank(B) <= min(k, n), so that the combined chain

n = rank(A*B) <=  min( rank(A), rank(B) ) <= min(k, n)

leaves not much wiggle space.

---

As the question, this answer is off-topic for SO and belongs to math.SE.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer which, by its author's own admission, is off-topic.

Comment: Please note that the answer is on-topic in relation to the question, but the subject matter of question and answer are off-topic for this venue.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If the entire question is off topic, shouldn't you down vote that, and not a valid answer?